# using inherited operators in derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading, derived-class

i'm having trouble using the overloaded operator< in a method(menorTamanhoque()) of my derived class.

i have the base class here:

```
class CAngulo
{
protected:
    int grau, minutos, segundos;
public:
    CAngulo(void);
    CAngulo(int g,int m, int s);
    CAngulo(const CAngulo &p);
    bool operator< (const CAngulo &p);

};

CAngulo :: CAngulo(void)
{
    grau=10;
    minutos=5;
    segundos=15;
}
CAngulo :: CAngulo(int g, int m ,int s)
{
    grau=g;
    minutos=m;
    segundos=s;
}
CAngulo :: CAngulo(const CAngulo &p)
{
    grau=p.grau;
    minutos=p.minutos;
    segundos=p.segundos;
}
bool CAngulo :: operator < (const CAngulo &p)
{
    if(grau>p.grau)
        return(false);
    else if(grau<p.grau)
            return(true);
    else if(grau==p.grau)
    {
        if(minutos>p.minutos) return(false);
        else if(minutos<p.minutos) return(true);
        else if(minutos==p.minutos)
        {
            if(segundos>p.segundos) return(false);
            else return(true);
        }

    }
}
```

and here i have the derived class where i want to use the overloaded operator above:

```
class CSetor : public CAngulo 
{ 
private:
    int raio;
public: 
    CSetor(void);
    CSetor(int g,int m, int s, int r);
    CSetor(const CSetor &p);
    bool menorTamanhoQue(const CSetor &a);
}; 
CSetor :: CSetor(void)
{
    grau=10;
    minutos=5;
    segundos=15;
    raio=10;
}
CSetor :: CSetor(int g, int m ,int s, int r)
{
    grau=g;
    minutos=m;
    segundos=s;
    raio=r;
}
CSetor :: CSetor(const CSetor &p)
{
    grau=p.grau;
    minutos=p.minutos;
    segundos=p.segundos;
    raio=p.raio;
}

bool CSetor :: menorTamanhoQue(const CSetor &a)
{
}
```

Dont know how to implement the last method menorTamanhoque
(i have to use the oveloaded < to compare c and d and check if this->raio < a.raio)

here is the main so you guys can understant what the program does:

```
int main()
{
    CAngulo a(10,10,10);
    CAngulo b(20,20,20);
    CSetor c(10,20,30,5);
    CSetor d(20,40,40,15);

    if(a < b) cout<<"a e menor que b"<<endl;
    else cout<<"a e maior que b"<<endl;

    if(c.menorTamanhoQue(d)) cout<<"c e menor que d"<<endl;
    else cout<<"c e maior que d"<<endl;

}
```

Comment: Your `bool menorTamanhoQue(const CSetor &a,const CSetor &b);` declaration does not match the later definition of that function, which has only one argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, your declaration of `menhorTamanhoQue` takes 2 arguments, but the definition takes one.

The declaration should be

```
bool menorTamanhoQue(const CSetor &a);
```

and then the definition should be

```
bool CSetor::menorTamanhoQue(const CSetor &a)
{
    return this->CAngulo::operator<(a)  // explicitly call base class operator<
           && this->raio < a.raio;  // and check raio
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/aA-8gB).

Comment: sorry ,the declaration of  menhorTamanhoQue was from a previous attempt, and i need to use the overloaded operator in the method